# Compare text from url in Google web app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a container bound script which sends the query result perfectly.

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var fn = e.parameter.FN;
  var key = e.parameter.KEY;

if ( fn == 'CSA' ) {
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("SubmittedAnswers");
    var data_raw = e.parameter.DATA.toString().replace("\n ", String.fromCharCode(10));
    var data = data_raw.split('|||| ');
    sh.appendRow(data);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("New record created");
  }

else if ( fn == 'QQ' ) {
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("QuestionBank");
    var rg = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    var rgq = sh.getName() + "!" + sh.getDataRange().getA1Notation();
    var sql = "Select A, B, C, D, E, F WHERE G IS NOT NULL";
    var qry = '=query(' + rgq + ';\"' + sql + '\";1)';
    var ts = ss.insertSheet();
    var setQuery = ts.getRange(1,1).setFormula(qry);
    var getResult = ts.getDataRange().getValues();
    ss.deleteSheet(ts); 
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(getResult));
  }
}
```

Now i'm trying to add something like a password so that without this none can run the script. I've tried the code below.

```js
else if ( fn == 'QQ' ) {
    var sheet_key = ss.getSheetByName("DashBoard").getRange(9,2).getValue;
    if (sheet_key == key) {
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("QuestionBank");
    var rg = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    var rgq = sh.getName() + "!" + sh.getDataRange().getA1Notation();
    var sql = "Select A, B, C, D, E, F WHERE G IS NOT NULL";
    var qry = '=query(' + rgq + ';\"' + sql + '\";1)';
    var ts = ss.insertSheet();
    var setQuery = ts.getRange(1,1).setFormula(qry);
    var getResult = ts.getDataRange().getValues();
    ss.deleteSheet(ts); 
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(getResult));
    }
  }
```

The sheet_key is perfectly in the "DashBoard" sheet at cell (9,2). Still the script is not returning anything. If i remove the IF part the script works fine :(

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `var sheet_key = ss.getSheetByName("DashBoard").getRange(9, 2).getValue;`

needs to be this: `var sheet_key = ss.getSheetByName("DashBoard").getRange(9, 2).getValue();`

This is something that is easy to do with the current editor